# Ext.js stick panel to window

Tags: extjs, window, panel

I need advanced look for window in Ext.js, like this:

[image]

Is there any standard way in Ext.js to stick object and window together, so they both drag together, resize etc.

I'm ready to dive into writing lot of custom code for that with huge number of different event, but I just want to be sure I don't miss the easier way!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about vertical tab, No.. by default extjs can't do that...
but, this can be done with some additonal plugin...

what version do you use ?
if ext 3.3 check this [url](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?113295-Vertical-Tab-Panel-Updated-to-work-w-ExtJS-3.3)
if ext 4, Monkee has been working hard on this [plugin](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137711-Vertical-Tabs-in-ExtJS4-Ext.ux.tab.VerticalPanel&highlight=vertical%20tab)

Comment: I have no problems creating vertical tabs. I looks for easy solution to attach this vertical tabs to window. So if I drag window tabs also drags etc...

Comment: have you try it ?? every component that attach to a window, will keep inside the window,.. even you drag it....

Comment: make sure there is no `renderTo` property on your vertical tabs

Comment: You see that on design, component is positioned outside of the window?

Comment: then the answer still NO,... you can't do that easily with just pure ext... solution that I suggest is you need to create your own class, extend from window, and mixins with vertical tabs panel..